# VB .NET Linq filter table rows

Tags: vb.net, linq

I need to use linq in vb.net (don't really care if its dot notation style or the other one)

I need to filter a DataTable that looks like this

legacyparent1, name1, id1

legacyparent1, name2, id2

legacyparent1, name1, id1

legacyparent1, name2, id2

legacyparent1, name1, id1

legacyparent1, name2, id2

I need just two rows with distinct name and id.

Its caused by a legacy join that I don't have time to try to rewrite right now.

Comment: I didn't provide the join because in this case I'm trying to fix the result via linq instead of fixing the sql query itself (I may have to hit the database additional times also if I go down that route). Typically, I am able to just get what I need first time around with sql but in this case I must use linq, which I am not particularly familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient, but here is the short way:

```
Dim dataTable2 = dataTable1.DefaultView.ToTable(true)
```

or a bit more efficient with hashed set:

```
Dim dt2 = dataTable1.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default).CopyToDataTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Distinct exists in 2 flavors that I know of. The first and default one can find distinct primitive types. For instance, if you wanted just the unique names you can run something like this `items.Select(Function(x) x.Name).Distinct()` to get just the names. To run distinct on multiple columns, you have to assist it with an IEqualityComparer.

Without a structure to work with, I created a class called Item that matches your data here. The following is the resulting code:

```
Public Class Item
    Public Property Parent As String
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property ID As String
End Class
```

The comparer can be anything. I've seen people use the class itself, to the form it the code is running in or a dedicated class as I have done here.

```
Public Class CompareThings
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Item)

    Public Overloads Function Equals(x As Item, y As Item) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Item).Equals
        Return x.ID = y.ID AndAlso x.Name = y.Name
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function GetHashCode(obj As Item) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Item).GetHashCode
        Return (obj.Name & obj.ID).GetHashCode()
    End Function
End Class
```

Finally, to see this in action, you run the following.

```
Dim things = New List(Of Item)(
{
    New Item With {.Parent = "legacyparent1", .Name = "name1", .ID = "id1"},
    New Item With {.Parent = "legacyparent1", .Name = "name2", .ID = "id2"},
    New Item With {.Parent = "legacyparent1", .Name = "name2", .ID = "id2"},
    New Item With {.Parent = "legacyparent1", .Name = "name1", .ID = "id1"},
    New Item With {.Parent = "legacyparent1", .Name = "name1", .ID = "id1"}
})

Dim cmp As New CompareThings()

Dim results = things.Distinct(cmp)

For Each res In results
    ' Console.WriteLine($"ID: {res.ID}, Name: {res.Name}")
    ' In case you are running an older version of .NET that doesn't have the above feature
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}, Name: {1}", res.ID, res.Name)
Next
```

That should give you just the two records you want.