# LINQ to get Distinct Count/Sort in List<List<string>>

Tags: c#, list, linq, count, nested

I have a `List<>` that contains a `List<string>`, of which I need to determine the unique count from the `List<string`, and order by the frequency of the count.

Example:

- "a","b","c"
- "d","e","f"
- "a","b"
- "a", "b", "c"
- "a", "b", "c"
- "a","b"

This would output (rank / combination / frequency)

- 1 - "a", "b", "c" - 3
- 2 - "a", "b" - 2
- 3 "d", "e", "f" - 1

I can come up with a brute-force approach but can this be done more elegantly with LINQ?  This isn't exactly a Cartesian approach from what I can tell.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to implement the `IEqualityComparer<T>` and use it to override how your lists are compared. The `Distinct` method in LINQ has an overload that accepts IEqualityComparer and you can use this to provide custom comparing thus treating each list as the same.- I recently answered a Distinct related question in VB but it should be easy to follow the steps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663909/vb-net-linq-filter-table-rows/44664169#44664169

Comment: @Fabulous Indeed. As well as `GroupBy` which is needed here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write your own `IEqualityComparer` and use it with `GroupBy`.

```
public class StringArrayValueComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<string>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<string> x, List<string> y)
        => x.SequenceEqual(y);

    public int GetHashCode(List<string> obj)
        => obj.Aggregate(1, (current, s) => current * 31 + s.GetHashCode());
}

var list = new List<List<string>>(new[]
{
    new List<string>(new [] { "a", "b", "c" }),
    new List<string>(new [] { "d", "e", "f" }),
    new List<string>(new [] { "a", "b" }),
    new List<string>(new [] { "a", "b", "c" }),
    new List<string>(new [] { "a", "b", "c" }),
    new List<string>(new [] { "a", "b" })
});

var orderedList = list
    .GroupBy(x => x, x => x, (x, enumerable) => new { Key = x, Count = enumerable.Count()}, new StringArrayValueComparer())
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
    .Select((x, index) => new { Rank = index + 1, Combination = x.Key, Frequency = x.Count });

foreach (var entry in orderedList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Rank} - {string.Join(",", entry.Combination)} - {entry.Frequency}");
}
```

> 1 - a,b,c - 3
>
> 2 - a,b - 2
>
> 3 - d,e,f - 1

Comment: You do not get rank this way. And even if you did not want to, creating dictionary without StringArrayValueComparer does not make much sense here.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek I've changed the code that the resulting type looks more like described in the question.

Comment: You deleted the question, but I would answer it anyway. Order of items in dictionary is not defined. While it actually preserves order quite often (and it may pass some tests) it is not guaranteed it would always behave this way. If you did not store the rank explicitely, the order was lost by the fact it was not reliably stored anywhere.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek I didn't know that. Thanks telling